# .htacess condition that rewrites if there is a subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess

I have two rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)? /negocio$2.php?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)? /negocio/?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```

They both work separately but using both creates a rewrite loop. I need to add a condition so the first one only applies when there is a subdirectory ($2 exists) and the opposite for the second one. Rewrite if ($2 doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$2 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.*)$ negocio$2.php?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$2 !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)?$ negocio/?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```